# How to convert this varchar values to a datetime

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert a varchar value that iI set up to a date time value. I want to load rows of a database into another database, but conversion is not going well.

This is my query:

```
select Krant
       , cast(jaar as varchar(4))+'-'
          +RIGHT('0'+cast(maand as varchar(2)),2)+'-'
          +RIGHT('0'+cast(dag as varchar(2)),2) as datum
       , Inhoud as artikel
       , LEN(Inhoud)-LEN(Replace(Inhoud,' ','')) as numwords
       , 'Goirle' as vestiging 
from [Sitecore_Bibliotheekmb_Krantenknipsel].[dbo].[KRANGOI]
```

The cast to Datum has to be a datetime value, but i am not getting it to work properly.  When i tried to cast to datetime it gave me an `out of range` exception.

These are the results of this query:

[alt text http://94.100.115.48/837450001-837500000/837478801-837478900/837478868_5_dE_7.jpeg](http://94.100.115.48/837450001-837500000/837478801-837478900/837478868_5_dE_7.jpeg)

I want the "Datum" field to be a Datetime field with the same values but in Datetime format. Could anyone help me please :).

Thanks,

Younes

Comment: When i tried to cast to datetime it gave me an out of range exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
select Krant, cast(cast(jaar as varchar(4))+'-'
  +RIGHT('0'+cast(maand as varchar(2)),2)+'-'
  +RIGHT('0'+cast(dag as varchar(2)),2) as datetime) as datum, 
  Inhoud as artikel, 
  LEN(Inhoud)-LEN(Replace(Inhoud,' ','')) as numwords, 
  'Goirle' as vestiging 
from [Sitecore_Bibliotheekmb_Krantenknipsel].[dbo].[KRANGOI]
```

Comment: That gives me the following exception: 
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 0):

You are not casting the Varchars to a Datetime

[CAST and CONVERT on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Can you try this:

```
SELECT CAST(('2010' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '06') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: In this post i just show my query + the results. I have tried to cast, but gives out of range :).

Comment: Yes the cast is working, what now? You have seen my query + results, this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: You must have some corrupt dates in those jaar, maand, dag fields?

Answer (score 0):

If any of your dates are earlier than 1753, a simple datetime type will not be sufficient. For this, you'd need to use the datetime2 datatype introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Also check that all values of **maand** and **dag** are valid days and months.